# How to copy values from tables in multiple files to one table in a single file with excel's VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple excel files with sheets like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

I would like to have a file with a table like this:

[image]

The third file is a merged file with all the values in right place.

Ps. I have to merge over 1000 files into 1 with all the columns sorted by name 
PPS I think that the whole file would have about 1000 columns (every column is a kind of object) and over 30000 rows

Can Someone Help me please?

Comment: Help? Sure, what have you tried?  Posting existing code gets quicker assistance...

Comment: Are the tables the only information on the sheets? Is there only one sheet per Workbook? if not are the tables named? or at least are they the only Table on a sheet, or in the workbook? are all the workbooks in the same directory? How can we possibly know what files need to be open what sheet in the file has the data you want, and what section of the sheet has the data?

Comment: multiple files with one sheet(sheet1) named "name1.xlsx" , "name2.xlsx" , etc... (the name is like the values of the second column of the sheet1). The tables are the only informations on the sheets. I open every file from a list in another excel file. I can copy all with a macro but I cannot place the right value at the right place in file all.xlsm (Sheet1). In the "sheet1" of the file all I have all the names of the columns in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your all file set up you could copy the header row into an array and compare the value with the first row of the other sheets

```
Dim HeadArray, CopyArray
Dim RowCountA as Long, RowCountB as Long
Dim ColumnA as Long, Column2 as Long

RowCountA = Workbooks("All").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
ColumnA = Workbooks("All").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Column
HeadArray = Workbooks("All").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).Resize(1,ColumnA)

'Will want to put the remaining code in a loop to accomodate the amount of files you are wanting
RowCountB = Workbooks("CopyBook").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
ColumnB = Workbooks("CopyBook").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Column
CopyArray = Workbooks("CopyBook").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).Resize(RowCountB,ColumnB)

For x = 0 to ColumnA - 1
    For i = 0 to ColumnB - 1
        If CopyArray(0,i) = HeadArray(0,x) Then
            For y = 1 to RowCountB - 1
                Workbooks("All").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCountA + y,x+1).Value = CopyArray(y - 1,i)
            Next y
        End if
    Next i
Next x

RowCountA = RowCountA + RowCountB
```

Comment: For this to work you are either going to need to put a heading for the first three columns or hard code in there copy

Comment: This doesn't help with duplicate column, or how to paste the information into the correct cells.

Comment: Workbooks("All").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCountA + y,x+1).Value = CopyArray(y - 1,i) sets the value.

Comment: As for duplicate column, the nested for's will put the data under the necessary columns.